# How to count how many times a value appears in a tree

Tags: c, tree, binary, binary-search-tree

I am to solve this problem, it loops through every node and finds the value, but crashes on returning, don't know why.

Obs.: In the problem it's said that an equal number goes to the right.

My code:

```
int conta(pNodo *arvore, int valor) {
    if (arvore == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (arvore->info == valor) {
            return (conta(arvore->dir, valor) + 1);
        }
        if (valor < arvore->info)
            conta(arvore->esq, valor);
        if (valor > arvore->info)
            conta(arvore->dir, valor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Besides that, simply calling `conta(arvore->esq, valor)` cannot be correct, because the function needs to return a value.

Comment: You are missing the `return` statement in the last 2 cases.

Comment: Obs: If "_an equal number goes to the right_", you could simply find the first instance, then use a `while()` loop to count them all... No need to annoy the stack diving deeper...

Answer (score 3):

You should *return* the findings in the leafs.

```c
int conta(pNodo* arvore, int valor) {
    if(arvore == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
       if(arvore->info == valor) {
        return(conta(arvore->dir, valor) + 1);
        }
        if(valor < arvore->info)
            return conta(arvore->esq, valor); /* add "return" here */
        if(valor > arvore->info)
            return conta(arvore->dir, valor); /* add "return" here */

        }
}
```

Comment: Because, as I said in the question, the problem tells me that an equal number goes to the right, not left.

Comment: @user3386109 By definition, a BST cannot store duplicate 'key' values... However, for this binary tree, one _could_ "splice" the 2nd '3' into the tree at the correct location. It's a bit more work, but it can be done. (A bit like "inserting a node at location x" in a linked list...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 A BST is just a representation of a sorted sequence. Since sorted sequences can contain duplicates, so can BST's. [See also the second sentence of the second paragraph here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Overview).

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks. I read that. I also read the first sentence in the article. The first sentence coincides with what I'd been taught. ("Avoid degenerates"). `:-)` (Aside: Funny that the article states "equal value nodes are found on the LEFT branch"... So many variations...)

Comment: @Fe2O3 But the first sentence in the article doesn't apply to the OP's situation. OP has a tree with duplicates, and OP's code treats it as a BST. Avoid narrow-minded pedantry.